# Kafka - read a pack of messages

Tags: apache-kafka, batch-processing, messaging, kafka-consumer-api

I have a batch job, which populates data to Kafka topic. Every message has data and job identifier.
On the consumer side, I want to only read messages, which belong to this job. After the job has finished and all the messages consumed, consumer side has to do some post processing.

1) If this is guaranteed, that no other messages will be produced during the job, how can I understand that job has finished and all the messages, produced by the job were consumed? (taking into consideration multiple partitions and asychrony).

2) If it is NOT guaranteed, that no other messages will be produced during the job, noise can be skipped, I believe.

Thanks

Comment: Are you tracking offsets somewhere yourself?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the `job_id` is constant. In that case, you can put a check in your consumer to shut down if `n` subsequent poll returns empty records from Kafka. `n` will depend on your ingestion rate and consumer poll interval.

Comment: Well, I believe it is quite a bad decision, as we have no guarantees on `n` subsequent empty pools mean everything was read

Comment: I know it's not the perfect solution but that's what came to my mind :) By any chance, are the number of messages produced by the batch job deterministic? Do we know it beforehand?

Answer (score 0):

I am only talking about the first case here. Mind you, this is just an idea and I have never tried it myself

You can use `endOffsets()`to get the last offsets of all the partitions and then loop over all of them after every message to check if all the current offsets match the ending offsets. If all are a match, you have reached the end.

Comment: Yes, I have also thought about this idea, but I am afraid it can affect performance significantly.